# How do I select the Roslyn engine?

Tags: mono, roslyn, scriptcs

I tried out [scriptcs](http://scriptcs.net) on OSX using a script that was previously written for the C# interactive (Roslyn) runtime and it fails with mysterious errors (which I tracked down to being related to C# 6.0 property syntax).

I read that scriptcs should support the Roslyn execution engine, and indeed I can see it is installed:

```
$ ls ~/.svm/versions/0.15.0/*Engine*
ScriptCs.Engine.Mono.dll     
ScriptCs.Engine.Roslyn.dll
```

Now, while the documentation tells me how to switch to the Mono engine (`-modules mono`), it does not tell me how to switch *from* Mono to Roslyn. I tried `-modules roslyn`, but saw no change (running with `-debug` shows that it executes my script using the Mono engine).

I must have missed something fundamental here. How do you switch to/force the Roslyn engine?